# Log::Log4perl: one appender to the file in UTF-8 and another to the screen in CP866 on win32

Tags: encoding, appender, perl, log4perl

I have **Log::Log4perl** config with two appenders to file and screen, like this:

```
  log4perl.logger.bc_log             = INFO, bc_log, console
  log4perl.appender.bc_log           = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
  log4perl.appender.bc_log.filename  = bc.log
  log4perl.appender.bc_log.layout    = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
  log4perl.appender.bc_log.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ISO8601}%d{Z} %H %m%n

  log4perl.appender.console           = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
  log4perl.appender.console.stderr    = 1
  log4perl.appender.console.layout    = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
  log4perl.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %m%n
```

In my program all output explicitly converted to **utf8** (from **cp1251** for example) and somewhere in my program:

```
my $bc_log = Log::Log4perl->get_logger('bc_log');
$bc_log->info('Some-utf8-encoded-string');
```

So message goes in **utf8** both to file and console, but I would like
**utf8** for file and **cp866** for console in one shot.
I can't figure out is it possible in **Log::Log4perl**?
Looks like **Log::Log4perl::Appender::File** has no encoding options.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new appender module (by copy original **Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen**) with decoding/encoding added and use it insteed of **Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen** in my code.